Fbx import/export to Unity has a scaling offset of 1.4
I'm having trouble importing an fbx from Unity into Blender, editing it then exporting it back as fbx to Unity.
When I reimport the mesh back into unity, it is too small with a factor of 1.4 scaling.
Unity after Blender import/export fbx.
Left: Original, Right: New.

Steps to reproduce:

Blender 3.5 file with following units settings.

Import FBX from Unity (the corresponding to the mesh file from the left pink hand image):
FBX file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16IJzTVwT3IS_fEhQF-UF5XqgsShZx913/view?usp=sharing
Import settings: Note the 0.1 on scale!



Do the edits I wanted. This is the blend file before my final export (all scalings applied).
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15LYdtkjAn0Bac6WQP-JIr0lQMT5Xxy_U/view?usp=sharing

Note: the dimensions seem logical: about 9 cm hand width for example.

This is the original fbx imported on top of my edited model, to show the scale has not changed overall (except on the thumb which is intended):




Export the FBX with these settings:


Note: I tried a lot of options:

Apply Scalings: All local / FBX Units Scale
Apply Units off/on
and many more.

When I then drag and drop my fbx into Unity, and drag the mesh inside it to an empty game object, I can see the result in the first image: the hand is smaller. I scaled the object to see what the offset was, and it was a factor of 1.4. All posts on scaling I find are either a factor 100/10 etc, but 1.4 I have no clue where it comes from. So for now I export with scaling 1.4 to make it work, but of course that is not ideal. This also happened in a previous project.
Why does this happen, but more importantly, how do I export the edited hand to the correct size without this weird scaling?
